# High CPU usage while using Saxon library

Tags: java, xml, performance, xslt, saxon

I am using Saxon Java library to merge two files. XSLT file is located [here](http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/#merge).

I find that even with two small xml files (~15 nodes each), CPU usage spikes when Saxon is merging files. I also tried using Saxon for other use case- modifying attribute of a small XML file (~15 nodes) and I found same result.

In general, is XSLT processing a CPU intensive task? or is it a known behavior of Saxon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that Oliver Becker's merge stylesheet has O(n^2) performance, that is, if you double the size of the input it takes four times as long. That's not a general property of XSLT, it's a property of the algorithm that Oliver is using. The code could probably be made a lot more efficient (though still quadratic) by taking advantage of XSLT 2.0's deep-equal() function, but a more radical overhaul than this would need the design of a different algorithm: for example a pre-processing pass through both trees that calculates a hash code for each node so that subsequent testing of whether two trees are equivalent is reduced to comparison of two hash codes.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO XSLT is very CPU intensive, but for a small file it should still be brief.

I suggest you write a simple benchmark to see how long it takes to convert a small file.  Make sure your JVM has warmed up by doing the translation at least 10,000x and test how long it takes when done repeatedly for at least 2 seconds AFTER it has warmed up.